# Wordpress: How to save values from repeater field?

Tags: wordpress

I am using this repeater plugin with a custom wordpress template https://github.com/DubFriend
/jquery.repeater

```
        <div class="repeater">
            <div data-repeater-list="category-group">
              <div data-repeater-item>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="cat-id"/>
                <input type="text" name="cat-title" />
                <input type="text" name="cat-slug" />
                <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Add"/>

        </div>
```

but values not saving in database

[image: Screenshot]

In save post function i have

```
add_shortcode('album','ty_front_end_form');

function ty_save_post_data() {

    if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['name_of_nonce_field'],'name_of_my_action') ) {
       print 'Sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
       exit;
    } else { 

        if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
            $title =  $_POST['title'];
        } else {
            echo 'Please enter a title';
            exit;
        }


        $release= $_POST['custom_release'];
        $artist = $_POST['custom_arname'];
        $lang = $_POST['custom_lang'];
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $catt = $_POST['cat-title'];
        $cats = $_POST['cat-slug'];

        $post = array(
            'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $title ),
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_type' => 'album',
            'meta_input' => array(
                'custom_release' => $release,
                'custom_arname' => $artist,
                'custom_lang' => $lang,
                'id' => $id,
                'cat-title' => $catt,
                'cat-slug' => $cats



            )
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post);



        $location = home_url(); 

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=$location' />";
        exit;
    } // end IF

}
```

and this is a shortcode for frontend user posting which is showing on a template page

Comment: Where are you calling `ty_save_post_data()`?

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/raw/EBy5DrB8.php and in the template i have
<div id="content" role="main">
  <?php
    
   

  ty_front_end_form();

 ?>

  </div>

Comment: Are you sure that data even exists? Are you correctly getting the data from the $_POST? Is the form returning the data?

Comment: Yes i am getting values by using $_POST

Comment: It's just not working for repeater field